# can SonarQUbe do a full analysis on a github pull request?

Tags: github, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm looking at integrating Sonarqube with our github instance. the one issue we're having is that SonarQube only supports preview analysis with Github currently, as opposed to a full one that includes code coverage. What we would ideally like is for SonarQube to do a full analysis of each pull request, and then post the outcome of this back to Github as a Github check. Is this possible?

Comment: You may be able to get away with running a full analysis without reporting to Github and then run the preview analysis with Github. Not the best solution, and I can't promise it will even work, but it's worth a shot.